# How can I access data in s3 bucket from one account to process the data using redshift in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

There is huge data in one of my AWS account in S3 Bucket and I want to process the data in some another AWS account using Redshift, I want to save the cost of data transfer and storage since I already have the data in first account.

Does Redshift provide this functionality to process data from a shared S3 bucket ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested myself practically, but you could refer any S3 bucket of any account while Copying or Unloading data to/from `S3` from/to `Redshift`. You simple has to supply the accurate `IAM` Role or `S3` credentials.

See the Copy or unload Syntax, it just ask for ACCESSKEY/SECRET, no account information.

```
  COPY sales FROM 's3://s3-path/to/data/data.csv'  CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=**********;aws_secret_access_key=*******'   FORMAT as CSV;
```

similarly unload command need same thing,

```
 unload ('SELECT * FROM example') TO 's3://path/to/S3/' credentials'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' delimiter '|' NULL AS '\\N' escape;
```